# Can I manage https, www and no .php redirects in only one redirection?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I´m working on redirections for a website that needs all the pages to have https and www, but also to remove the extension from any .php file.

I was able to manage the https + www in only one redirection, but I´m not sure if I can include the .php removal line in the same sentence and combine everything in only one redirect.

```
#HTTPS + WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Right now, any internal file endind with ".php" has to go through two different redirects to meet the requirements.

http://example.com/file.php > https://www.example.com/file.php > https://www.example.com/file

Is there a way to make it one redirect? The idea is that it still works for anything else within the domain, but if the file ends with .php it gets redirected to non .php

Answer (score 0):

Changing this sentence

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

to

```
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule https://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

And adding it to the top (before the https redirection) did the trick. 
This way, if the file ends with ".php" it gets automatically redirected to https and www so the rest of the conditions don´t apply. Otherwise, it just takes the https www redirection that is below.

Comment: Did not work as expected. It´s not removing .php now.